# SQL: No records in the last week

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with different columns. Two of them are user and data. I want to find which users have no records in the last week.

How far have I arrived:

This gives me well the records ordered first by user and then by date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1  
ORDER BY user, date
```

I also could find a way to store one week in a var:

```
$oneWeek = strtotime("-1 week");
$oneWeek = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $oneWeek);
echo $oneWeek . "<br>";
```

Is there a way I can select the users that do not have any records in the last seven days?

Comment: What "week" are you talking about? The past seven days? Last calendar week according to local definition on what is the first day of the week? Last calendar week according to ISO?

Comment: the last 7 days, count from today

Comment: Do you know what's wrong with my question? why the negative points? I want to improve and make better questions

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your request. I don't understand this behavior either. Why would anyone downvote and not leave a message as to the whys? You don't have "a database with different columns" by the way. You have a database containing tables. The tables have columns.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT t1.user
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.user
HAVING MAX(t1.date) < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

This returns users whose maximum date is more than a week in the past.  That is another way of saying that there are no records in the past week.

Comment: It seems to work but I just do not understand. Can you explain your code, please?

Comment: Do you know what's wrong with my question? why the negative points? I want to improve and make better questions